# Finding out why QGIS plugin is rejected

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have a selection of python plugins (one rather large one) that I have developed under Qgis 1.8 and that I am migrating to qgis 2.0.  The error that the Plugin Manager gives me when I load these plugins (This plugin was developed under 1.x) is rather unhelpful.  It also arises in situations that have nothing to do with the API Version.  For instance, a Network error yesterday introduced a stream of random characters into a few of my code files (Fun!) and this led to the Plugin Manager telling me my plugin was old. Eventually, I found out that a tab and a dollar sign had been inserted in front of a comment in my metadata.txt, and that was the problem.

Is there any way to see a more detailed error when QGIS 2 rejects a plugin as 1.x?

If not a proper trace, then at least what class, or even what file was rejected?

The instructions regards API changes at the [Qgis Hub Wiki](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20) are not as useful as a simple error message.

Comment: Did you change your QGisMinimumVersion tag according to this (http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20#Plugin-repository-and-metadata-changes) ?

Comment: Yes, in fact my first step in migration is to use QGIS 2.0's version of Plugin Builer to rebuild the basic plugin, and then copy in my code in piece by piece, modifying as I go according to the wiki.  So, the metadata.txt I don't even mess with, and it has just what QGIS 2 wants.  Once I removed the random characters from the comments, the plugin was recognized as being of the proper version.  So, I understand the migration process, I just want to know how to see some real errors when QGIS thinks my plugin is old.